# How do make the JVM recognize a scala.Array[T] as a java array T[] in a polymorphic method call?

Tags: java, scala, polymorphism, slf4j, jvm-languages

The problem can be found in the following code:

```
      def debug[T](format: String, arg1:T, arg2:Any, args:Any*):T = {
        logger.debug(format, (arg1 :: arg2 :: args.toList).toArray)
        arg1
      }
```

Since what I pass as the second parameter is an array of Any's, this code should have called SLF4J's debug method

```
      public void debug(String format, Object[] argArray);
```

Yet

```
      public void debug(String format, Object arg);
```

ends up being called instead.

**Let me give an example.**

When I call

```
    debug("The four parameters are {} as String, {} as Integer, {} as String and {} as Integer.", "1", 2, "3", 4)
```

It logs

```
    DEBUG - The four parameters are [1, 2, 3, 4] as String, {} as Integer, {} as String and {} as Integer.
```

Instead of

```
    DEBUG - The four parameters are 1 as String, 2 as Integer, 3 as String and 4 as Integer.
```

NOTE1: I assumed the first call would work based on the [scala.Array Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html).

> Represents polymorphic arrays. Array[T] is Scala's representation for Java's T[].

NOTE2: The code that originated my question can be found at https://github.com/alexmsmartins/UsefullScalaStuff/blob/master/src/main/scala/alexmsmartins/log/LoggerWrapper.scala

This is a small wrapper around slf4j that I use in my Scala projects.

Comment: You may be aware of http://software.clapper.org/grizzled-slf4j. It solves the performance issue the other way, which is to forgo the string interpolation in favour of passing a block returning a string which is only evaluated when required.

Comment: I didn't knew this project at all. Never the less, my goal when doing this Wrapper was to make every method where it makes sense return a parameterized type T instead of Unit. To me this makes much more sense in a functional language like scala. Maybe I should look into it and take some ideas from their code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an `Array[Any]`, not an `Array[Object]`. You could try changing your types from `Any` to `AnyRef` (in which case you'll not be able to pass `AnyVal`'s such as `Int`). You could also call `.asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]]` after `.toArray`, which, in this one particular case, shouldn't give you trouble because the erasure is the same.

Comment: But the .asInstanceOf[Array[AnyRef]] applied after 'toArray' worked. This is strange!

Comment: I'm not completely enlightened but I guess this only means that I have to read something about erasures. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use: `(arg1 :: args2 :: args.toList).toSeq: _ *` - see how `StringLike.format` works

Your choice of list creation will cause quite a bit of overhead in terms of object creation for a debug call (certainly it negates any benefit of reducing array creation IMHO)

Comment: You're absolutely right about the performance impact. Still I wanted to have a working wrapper that handles a vaiable number of parameters before worrying about that.

But if you have a better way about how to go about it go ahead. I would appreciate it! :D

Comment: Apparently not working ->  

overloaded method value debug with alternatives:
[error]   (org.slf4j.Marker,java.lang.String)Unit <and>
[error]   (java.lang.String,java.lang.Throwable)Unit <and>
[error]   (java.lang.String,Array[java.lang.Object])Unit <and>
[error]   (java.lang.String,Any)Unit
[error]  cannot be applied to (String, Any)
[error]     logger.debug(format, (arg1 :: arg2 :: args.toList

___ Let me see if I can understand why.